# Web-Api dontnet core 2.2 running on centos 7 mysql not working

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I built this [creating-web-apis-using-asp-net-and-mysql-in-5-minutes](https://www.mydatahack.com/creating-web-apis-using-asp-net-and-mysql-in-5-minutes/)

The api runs fine on my local machine windows 10 with visual studio 2017 enterprise.  I have a `centos` box running on VMware in another location this is where my MySQL database is.  When I run the api on my local machine I use a connection string with a FQDN and the api runs fine.  FYI the api also has a method without database access that basically sends back a json string ["value1","value2"] both this and the one that gets a user from MySQL work fine on local machine.

Next I set it up as a service on the `Centos` box and set up `apache` to proxy to the `kestrel` web server at `localhost:5000` using these instructions [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2).  my Apache virtual host config is the same as the one in the example except no server alias and no logging.  I didn't want a server alias and the logging commands stopped the service from starting.  I also needed to upgrade apache from the Centos's repo apache `2.4.6` to Apache `2.4.36` I think.

I did this using a third party repo because `RequestHeader` set  `"X-Forward-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST SCHEME}` needed Apache `2.4.10` or above.

It should be stated that I used my own database and not the example one it is basic just returns user info like `uname` etc.

If I run `http://MyFQDN/api/values` I get the desired response.

If run `http://MyFQDN/api/users/1` which when run on my local machine while debugging returns a json string with the correct information using a MySQL connection string with a FQDN and not `localhost:3306` or `127.0.0.1:3306` as the server in the connection string. When I try it on the Linux box no go.

Instead I get the infamous http `500` error which I believe means that program is not running correctly the only difference here is the MySQL connection string or there is something else.

in the demo it says

> Some values (for example, SQL connection strings) must be escaped for the configuration providers to read the environment variables. Use the following command to generate a properly escaped value for use in the configuration file

However I have tried several times using the example

systemd-escape … see demo for exact syntax as it doesn't escape well here funny.

I believe if I had a properly escaped MySQL connection string that would work on kestrel in the Centos box it might work.

This is in `appsettings.production.json`

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevDatabase": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=nameOfDatabase;Uid=svcuser;Pwd=Password;"
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

________--------UPDATE

So I am trying to attach the visual studio debugger to the web-api using ssh which I believe should let me walk through the code while it is running on the Centos box and find the error.

Here is link to instructions to do just that (FYI no luck yet) [Link to instructions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/debugging-net-core-on-unix-over-ssh/)

Any advice on this or some other help always accepted

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect the `MySQL` by `mysql -u svcuser -p` ?  If not, make sure the `mysqld` has been started and the credential is correct . Also, it would be nice to show the the error info .

Comment: I'll check but remember the api runs fine on the development windows 10 box with the credentials plus I created the svcuser user just for the service and gave it read only because thats what I need now.  I need to find in the logs what is happening and don't really know where to look because the only error I get is the 500 error from kestrel over the net

Comment: I tried MySQL -u -p with svcuser and had trouble logging in i'm not sure why I had given that user a % in from host in sql  workbench.  So I switched to a user with only local host login privileges MySQL -u newuser -p worked but changed it in the api still no go.  thanks though

Answer (score 0):

use the instructions under my update.  I am now able to run the web-api on the Linux box through any browser and step through the code on my machine …….

I have a null object at my connection string from the .json file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<sPPContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("changedButFrom.json")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

    }
```

the error happens on the line where I put changedButFrom.json  I am confident it is the escaping of the connection string that is causing the problem before I wasn't sure what the problem was

Great tool